# Как перезапустить сервер без доступа по ssh?

Tags: linux, сервер, arp

После перезагруски сервер с удаленным доступом не "взлетел". Отвечает на icmp ping но ssh молчит. Сервер без физического доступа.

Сервер Dell R730 с iDRAC, но сам порт не подключен к комутатору.

Если способ перезпустить или подлючится к нему?

Comment: если сможете удалённо нажать кнопку reset (вариант: отключить и включить питание), то ответ на ваш вопрос: «да, можно».

Comment: Возможно кто-то блокирует подключение по ssh, снимите блокировку - подключитесь

Comment: А этот самый iDRAC кто нибудь настраивал ? Если да, подключайтесь через него. Если нет ... ну надо настраивать такие вещи заранее

Comment: чисто из любопытства, а почему на вопросе метка `arp`?

Comment: Никак. Попросить местных перезагрузить ещё раз и снять на мабилу бегущие строки.

Comment: и у меня также) на ссх молчит. захожу на него - ссх живой, всё ок, но не отвечает извне)

Comment: @Fat-Zer если дождусь оператора подлючит провод к iDRAC будет возможность присвоить ip. Там DHCP по дефолту был.